# How to stub a method in ActiveSupport::TestCase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testcase

In `RSpec` I could stub method like this:

```
allow(company).to receive(:foo){300}
```

How can I stub a method with `ActiveSupport::TestCase`?

I have a test like this.

```
class CompanyTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test 'foobar' do
    company = companies(:base)
    #company.stubs(:foo).returns(300)
    assert_nil(company.calculate_bar)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Minitest comes with a `stub` method out of the box, in case you don't wanna use external tools:

```
require 'minitest/mock'
class CompanyTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test 'foobar' do
    company = companies(:base)
    Company.stub :foo, 300 do
      assert_nil(company.calculate_bar)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Minitest has some limited functionality for mocks, but I'd suggest using  the [mocha](https://github.com/freerange/mocha) gem for these kinds of stubs.

The syntax for Mocha is exactly what you have on the commented out line:

```
class CompanyTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test 'foobar' do
    company = companies(:base)
    company.stubs(:foo).returns(300)
    assert_nil(company.calculate_bar)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Enhancing @Farrukh answer:

If you want to verify the arguments passed, like  `allow(company).to receive(:foo).with(some_args).and_return(300)`,

You can use `assert_called_with`.

```
# requiring may not be needed, depending on ActiveSupport version
require "active_support/testing/method_call_assertions.rb"
include ActiveSupport::Testing::MethodCallAssertions  # so we can use `assert_called_with`
 
assert_called_with(company, :foo, some_args, returns: 300) do
  assert_nil(company.calculate_bar)
end
```