# How can I stub in setup method with Minitest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I use `stub` method in `setup`?
I only found the `stub` with block like this:

```
class FooTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test 'for_something' do
    Foo.stub :some_method, 3 do
      #assert_equal
    end
  end  
end
```

But I want to stub for all tests. How can I stub it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve that by overriding `#run` method in your test case:

```
class FooTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def run
    Foo.stub :some_method, 3 do
      super
    end
  end

  test 'for_something' do
    #assert_equal
  end  
end
```

It's a common way to introduce the code that needs to be executed "around" every test case.

Answer (score 2):

I think this already answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/39081919/3102718

With gem [mocha](https://github.com/freerange/mocha) you can stub methods in setup or in test, e.g.:

```
require 'active_support'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'mocha/mini_test'

module Foo
end

class FooTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  setup do
    Foo.stubs(:some_method).returns(300)
  end

  test 'for_something' do
    assert Foo.some_method == 300
  end
end
```